# why can't I delete my answer

Tags: support, moderators, reputation, answers

My answer was posted twice by mistake, but I am allowed only to "vote" for deleting it.
is it because I dont have enough reputation? Why can't  I delete my answer?

Comment: A link would help, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Looks deleted to me.

Users have a binding vote when it comes to deleting their own answers (it's a bit more complicated for questions). Similarly, they have a binding undelete vote *if* they were the ones who deleted it in the first place.